# how to convert Gregorian format to Solar format in mysql using of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp, unix-timestamp

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  OrderDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
)
```

When I Insert a row, my output will be like this:

```
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-01 16:22:47 |   // Gregorian date
+---------------------+
```

Now I need to convert it to **Solar** date, like this:

```
+---------------------+
| 1394-05-10 16:22:47 |   // Solar date
+---------------------+
```

How can I do that ?

I have a idea, I can use of `unix_timestamp` for changing the date (Gregorian) to a timestamp (like this: `1438438368` ), and then plus it with `1348-10-11` (`1348-10-11 = 1970-01-01`)

In fact I need to plus a date with a number like this:

```
(1438438368) + (1348-10-11) = something that I want
```

how can I do that ?

Comment: no reference to `Solar date` on google. interwebs is broken !!

Comment: then what should I do ? @amdixon

Comment: just a joke - im trying to suggest you should post a reference on what a Solar date is so people can assist

Comment: look [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_calendar)

Comment: No, you look [this](http://jdf.scr.ir/download/). And please spend some time to [understand the basics first](http://jdf.scr.ir/). After that, you can try the @mehdi 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<?php
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter("fa_IR@calendar=persian", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'Asia/Tehran', IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL);
echo $fmt->format(time());
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

use [JDF](http://jdf.scr.ir/) .

```
$now = time();
jdate('Y-m-d h:i:s',$now)
```

Comment: You should import jdf.php at the first then this code will works correctly

Comment: Look, thanks for your solution, +1 vote up for you. But I prefer to don't use of a external file and then `include()` it, I like to go with my solution.

Comment: JDF has more functions to different works ... see this page http://jdf.scr.ir/rahnama/   it really  worth it to import , by the way some times we should import library instead of focus on everything .. Good luck